# ggplot2 fix overlapping y-labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis-labels

**Code example**
Let me take this little example:

```
example.data <- data.frame(
  x = seq(1,5),
  y = c(seq(1,3), 4.1, 4.11),
  y.label = letters[1:5]
)


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(example.data, aes(x=x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = example.data$y, labels = example.data$y.label)
```

Since 4.1 and 4.11 are extremely close to one another the labels will overlap:

[image]

**Info** 
I plot a very similar graph for a publication and do not want to increase the size of the figure just to make the labels fit (which would require the plot to be very large). I'm familiar with [`ggrepel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html), but as far as I know this only works for text annotation within the plot itself and not for axis.

**Question**
How can I make sure that the labels do not overlap without having to increase the size of the whole plot?

Comment: Is the y-axis really a categorial variable? In the case of this example, I would switch the two axis, which would also be a more natural way of displaying the data. Like this `ggplot(example.data, aes(x=y.label, y = y)) + 
        geom_point()`

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather do it this way. Draw one normal plot and a second magnified version. Then overlay them using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5220641/6574038).

```
p1 <- ggplot(example.data, aes(x=x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = example.data$y[1:4], labels = example.data$y.label[1:4])

p2 <- ggplot(example.data, aes(x=x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlim(3.9, 5.1) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(4.100, 4.111, .002), labels=c("d", rep("", 4), "e"),
                     limits=c(4.1, 4.111))

vp <- grid::viewport(width=0.4, height=0.15, x=.8, y=.4)

png("plot.png")
print(p1)
print(p2, vp=vp)
dev.off()
```

***Result***

[image]

It becomes even clearer with a reader's guide:

```
library("ggforce")
p1 <- p1 + geom_circle(aes(x0=4.5, y0=4.2, r=.7), 
                       inherit.aes=FALSE, linetype=2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=4.5, y=2.5, xend=4.5, yend=3.5),
               size=1, arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.5, "cm")))
```

***Refined result***

[image]

*Note:* Of course you can still refine that, just to get you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different plot for this problem:

```
ggplot(example.data, aes(x=y.label, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 4.1) +
    geom_text(aes(0,4.1,label = 4.1,hjust=-1,  vjust = -0.5))
```

[image: Changed axis plot]