# Manually inset boxplots over a map made using geom_sf in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm looking to manually inset several boxplots over a `geom_sf` map made in ggplot. I have found several examples of overlays/insets on `geom_polygon` but not `geom_sf` specifically, which seems to work differently. The example below produces a map `p.map` and boxplot `p.box`.

Example code here:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

p.map <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, aes(fill = AREA)) +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m no_defs") +
  theme_void()

p.box <- ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = hp, group = factor(cyl))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

I wish to inset the boxplot on the map in a way to produce something like this (though with translucent background):
[image]

Is there a way to do this with `geom_sf` layers?

Here is my `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rmapshaper_0.4.4 ggspatial_1.1.4  here_0.1         rgdal_1.5-16     ggplot2_3.3.0    sf_0.9-6         sp_1.4-1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.1.0   purrr_0.3.4        lattice_0.20-41    V8_3.2.0           colorspace_1.4-1   vctrs_0.3.2        generics_0.0.2     yaml_2.2.1        
 [9] rlang_0.4.7        geojsonlint_0.4.0  e1071_1.7-3        pillar_1.4.3       foreign_0.8-78     glue_1.4.0         httpcode_0.3.0     withr_2.2.0       
[17] DBI_1.1.0          lifecycle_0.2.0    geojsonio_0.9.2    rgeos_0.5-5        munsell_0.5.0      gtable_0.3.0       labeling_0.3       maptools_0.9-9    
[25] curl_4.3           class_7.3-16       Rcpp_1.0.4.6       KernSmooth_2.23-16 scales_1.1.0       backports_1.1.6    classInt_0.4-3     jsonvalidate_1.1.0
[33] jsonlite_1.6.1     farver_2.0.3       digest_0.6.25      dplyr_1.0.1        grid_4.0.0         rprojroot_1.3-2    jqr_1.1.0          tools_4.0.0       
[41] magrittr_1.5       lazyeval_0.2.2     geojson_0.3.4      tibble_3.0.1       crul_1.0.0         crayon_1.3.4       pkgconfig_2.0.3    ellipsis_0.3.0    
[49] rstudioapi_0.11    R6_2.4.1           units_0.6-7        compiler_4.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

So I've realized that I was using the wrong wording when searching for answers; I should have been searching for "inset" rather than "overlay". Just goes to show the importance of searching for the right things!

The example I used from here ([It is possible to create inset graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219671/it-is-possible-to-create-inset-graphs)) used `viewports` from the `grid` package that is called by ggplot.

For my own reference and anyone else that happens to stumble upon this question, here is some code that worked for me.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# Setting up the map
p.map <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc, aes(fill = AREA)) +
  coord_sf(crs = "+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m no_defs") +
  theme_void()

# Setting up the boxplot
p.box <- ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = hp, group = factor(cyl))) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = alpha("white", 0.4), colour = NA))

# Printing out the figure and inserting the inset using a viewport
png("inset_plot.png", width = 10, height = 8, units = "in", res = 200)
print(p.map)
# width, height, x, and y are relative values to figure dimensions
subvp <- grid::viewport(width = 0.2, height = 0.2, x = 0.5, y = 0.3)
print(p.box, vp = subvp)
dev.off()
```

This produces the following figure:
[image]

Of course this will require a lot of manual tweaking so there may be better methods for this. I will update this answer as I experiment more with my own data.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to overlay both plots as Grobs onto a blank canvas.  Something like this

```
ggplot() + annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(p.map),
  xmin = 0, xmax = 1,
  ymin = 0, ymax = 1) 
         + annotation_custom(grob = ggplotGrob(p.box),
  xmin = 0.1, xmax = 0.4,
  ymin = 0.6, ymax = 0.8)
```

You will need to play about with the coordinates, etc.

[image]